# Deleting records from custom Wordpress database - Ajax/JSon way

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress

I went thru earlier answers, but I just cant get my code working. How do I even use `ajax/json/javascript` on `Wordpress?` They dont seem to work at all? I use `php/mysql` thru php_everywhere.

Im getting records from my custom table `(id, username, syke, rate, etc)` with `$wpdb`. My output table needs a button to delete certain row by autoincrement id.

All help appreciated.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>

<th>Syke</th>
<th>Kesto</th>

</tr>

<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username= $current_user->user_login;
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM syke where username = '$username'" );
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $print->rate .'</td>';
echo '<td>' . $print->kesto .'</td>';

echo '</tr>';
}
?>

</table>
```

Comment: where is the delete functionality?....

Comment: @kasvi, please let me know what you are getting right now and what you wants in expected output, might be i will help you. thanks

Comment: Oh theres no delete function at the moment. There was an input button with class delete, but couldnt get it working with json.

Comment: I tried to lookup the code I used, didnt find it for now. Anyway, there should be a button at the end of every row at output table that would execute ajax/json to delete that record.

Does WP need some special setting to run ajax/json?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way... wasn't what I wanted though. There's still one problem though.. How do I add another condition? where id=$_GET['id'] AND username=$username?

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username= $current_user->user_login;
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->prefix . 'xxx', [ 'ID' => $_GET['id'] ], [ '%d' ] );
}?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
     <th>Syke</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

<?php       
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM xxx where username = '$username'" );
        foreach ( $result as $print )   {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->rate  .'</td>';
          echo  '<td>' . '<a href="xxx.xxx.xxx?id=' . $print->id .  '">x</a>' . '</td>';


          echo '</tr>';
                                        }
?>
</table>
```